# General version of $d$-separation

Tags: reference-request, pr.probability, st.statistics

I find the $d$-separation criterion (see, e.g., [Theorem 2 here](https://ftp.cs.ucla.edu/pub/stat_ser/r130-reprint.pdf); note however the preceding definition, which basically means we are treating discrete random variables) a really useful sufficient criterion for conditional independence of random variables. However, I am struggling to find a general version for arbitrary random variables, say with values in a Polish space (where conditional independence is defined via the respective disintegrations).

**My question:** Is there a version of $d$-separation that treats arbitrary Polish spaces valued random variables, or at least arbitrary $\mathbb{R}^d$ valued random variables?

*To make the post self-contained:* Let $\pi \in \mathcal{P}(S_1\times S_2 \times \dots \times S_N)$ be a Borel probability measure on the polish space $S_1 \times ... \times S_N$. Assume there is a directed acyclic graph with nodes $\{1, 2, \dots, N\}$, where without loss of generality the nodes are increasing in topological order (i.e., there is no edge pointing from $k$ to $l$ for $k > l$). Denote by $pa(k)$ the set of parents of a node $k$. Assume $\pi$ has a regular disintegration of the form
$$
\pi = \pi_{1} \otimes \pi_{2, pa(2)} \otimes \pi_{3, pa(3)} \otimes \dots \otimes \pi_{N, pa(N)},
$$
where $\pi_{k, pa(k)}$ is a stochastic kernel mapping from $(\otimes_{j \in pa(k)} S_j)$ to $\mathcal{P}(S_k)$.
Note that this disintegration naturally encodes certain conditional independencies. Indeed, if $(X_1, X_2, \dots, X_N) \sim \pi$ is a random variable with distribution $\pi$, the given disintegration means that $X_k$ is conditionally independent of $\{X_j : j \in \{1, ..., k-1\}\backslash pa(k)\}$ given $\{X_j : j \in pa(k)\}$.

On the other hand, this disintegration also implies many other conditional independences between the variables, and $d$-separation is a criterion to identify all of them (atleast for discrete spaces). The definition of $d$-separation is as follows: Take disjoint $A, B, C \subset \{1, \dots, N\}$. We say that $C$ $d$-separates $A$ and $B$, if there are no paths from a node $i \in A$ to a node $j \in B$ which is not blocked by a node in $C$. A path between nodes is blocked if either of the following criteria is satisfied:

1. there is a chain element $a \rightarrow b \leftarrow c$ contained in the path such that $b \not \in C$ and none of the descendants of $b$ is in $C$.
2. there is a chain element $a \rightarrow b \rightarrow c$ or $a \leftarrow b \rightarrow c$ contained in the path such that $b \in C$.

Then the fundamental result we want is that if $C$ $d$-separates $A$ and $B$, then $\{X_j : j\in A\}$ and $\{X_j : j \in B\}$ are conditionally independent given $\{X_j : j \in C\}$ (all under $\pi$, of course).

Comment: The linked paper appears to be non-mathematical. In particular, the apparently crucial definition contains the apparently incomprehensible phrase "subsets of variables of a distribution", and the sentence containing this phrase appears to be non-grammatical. So, it might help if you make your post self-contained.

Comment: @IosifPinelis: Thanks for you comment! A part of my question is basically "is there a mathematically rigorous&general treatment of this". The phrase you mention parses as follows for me: We have a joint distribution of $(X_1, X_2, \dots, X_N)$ and now we take three disjoint subsets $J, K, L \subset \{1, \dots, N\}$ and look at $\{X_i : i \in J\}, \{X_i: i \in K\}, \{X_i: i\in L\}$, and are interested in conditional independence of the first two sets of variables conditioned on the third.

Comment: Thank you for this clarification. Still, I think it might help if you make your post self-contained, with the reference to the linked paper playing only an auxiliary role.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there are more general versions of the $d$-separation criterion, in particular also for standard Borel spaces (i.e. Polish spaces).

For completeness, the classical version of $d$-separation (i.e. on discrete random variables) has been generalized several times to the best of my knowledge.

#### 1. $d$-separation for absolute continuous probability distributions

Lauritzen et al. (see [Independence Properties of Directed Markov Fields](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/epdf/10.1002/net.3230200503)) showed that the $d$-separation criterion holds for absolute continuous probability distributions with respect to a product measure. More specifically, let $\mathcal{H}_1, \ldots, \mathcal{H}_n$ be measurable spaces and $P$ a probability distribution on $\prod_{i=1}^{n} \mathcal{H}_i$ such that
$$P(X_1 \in E_1, \ldots, X_n \in E_n) = \int_{x_1 \in E_1} \cdots \int_{x_n \in E_n} f(x_1,\ldots, x_n) \ \mu_1(\mathrm{d} x_1) \otimes \cdots \otimes \mu_n(\mathrm{d} x_n)$$
where $E_i$ is measurable, $f$ being a density and $\mu_i$ being a measure on $\mathcal{H}_i$. In this situation, a distribution $P$ is called **compatible** with a DAG $G$ (with vertices $\{1, \ldots, n\}$) if the density $f$ factorizes as
$$f(x_1, \ldots, x_n) = \prod_{i=1}^{n} f(x_i | x_{\textsf{pa}(i)}) \quad \mu\textrm{-a.e.}$$
where $\textsf{pa}(i)$ is the set of parents of vertex $i$ and $f(x_i | x_{\textsf{pa}(i)})$ is the conditional density of $X_i$ given its parents.

Theorem 1 in the reference shows that the following two statements are equivalent

- $P$ is compatible with $G$
- $P$ satisfies the global Markov property, i.e. for every disjoint triple of subsets $A,B,C \subseteq \{1, \ldots, n\}$ such that $C$ d-separates $A$ and $B$ in $G$, we have that
  $$f(x_A, x_B, x_C) = f(x_A | x_C) \cdot f(x_B | x_C) \cdot f(x_C) \quad \mu\textrm{-a.e.},$$
  i.e. $\{X_i: i\in A\}$ is cond. independent of $\{X_j: j \in B\}$ given $\{X_k: k\in C\}$.

#### 2. $d$-separation for standard Borel spaces (i.e. Polish spaces)

A version of the $d$-separation criterion (with several other equivalent conditions) for standard Borel spaces has been proven in by P. Forré and J. Mooij ([Markov Properties for Graphical Models with Cycles and Latent Variables](https://arxiv.org/abs/1710.08775)). Your desired version is stated in Theorem 3.2.1. ($3. \Longleftrightarrow 6.$)

In this setting a probability distribution on standard Borel spaces $\prod_{i=1}^n \mathcal{H}_i$ given by
$$P(X_1 \in E_1, \ldots, X_n \in E_n) = \int_{x_1 \in E_1} \cdots \int_{x_n \in E_n} P(\mathrm{d} x_1, \ldots, \mathrm{d} x_n)$$
with $E_{i} \in \mathcal{H}_i$ is **compatible** with a DAG $G$ if
$$P(\mathrm{d} x_1, \ldots, \mathrm{d} x_n) = \prod_{i = 1}^n P(\mathrm{d} x_i | x_{\textsf{pa}(i)})$$
where $P(\mathrm{d} x_i | x_{\textsf{pa}(i)})$ is the regular conditional probability distribution of $X_i$ given its parents in $G$.
In Theorem 3.2.1. ($3. \Longleftrightarrow 6.$) it is proven that the following two statements are equivalent:

- $P$ is compatible with $G$
- $P$ satisfies the global Markov property, i.e. for every disjoint triple of subsets $A, B, C \subseteq \{1,\ldots, n\}$ such that $A$ is $d$-separated from $B$ by $C$, we have that $\{X_i: i\in A\}$ is cond. independent of $\{X_j: j \in B\}$ given $\{X_k: k\in C\}$ where conditional independence is defined via regular conditional probabilities.

#### 3. $d$-separation on Markov categories

As already mentioned in the question, conditional independence is defined via regular conditional probability distributions in all examples considered.

Recently, Tobias Fritz and me showed the $d$-separation criterion in the more abstract setting of Markov categories (see [The $d$-Separation Criterion in Categorical Probability](https://arxiv.org/abs/2207.05740)). There we have shown that whenever you can do an operation that behaves like Bayesian disintegration (i.e. whenever conditionals exist), the $d$-separation criterion applies.

This result includes the $d$-separation criterion on standard Borel spaces and finite probability distributions as specific instances. But it also includes non-probabilistic settings, where $d$-separation applies.

For example, it implies that the $d$-separation criterion also applies to finite possibilistic networks, i.e. networks where a conditional $f(x | a)$ specifies whether $x \in X$ is possible or impossible given $a \in A$ by setting $f(x | a) = 1$ or $f(x|a) = 0$.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Theorem 2 in the linked paper readily extends to variables taking values in polish spaces. The needed observation is that if the underlying random variables
$X_1,\ldots,X_n$ take values in a Polish space $\Upsilon$, then the following equivalence holds:

$X_J$ and $X_K$ are conditionally independent given $X_L$ iff for all Borel functions $f:\Upsilon \to {\mathbb Z}$ with finite range,  $f(X_J)$ and $f(X_K)$ are conditionally independent given the $\sigma$-field determined by $X_L$.

Here $f(X_L)$ is shorthand for the sequence $\{f(x_\ell)\}_{\ell \in L}$.

Comment: You are right, that seems to cover it. Is there a reference for the result you state?

Comment: About the result you state, I slightly doubt that the "only if" direction holds (take $J=\{1\}, K = \{2\}, L=\{3\}$, $X_1 = X_2 = -X_3$, then it seems we can destroy the conditional independence quite easily by applying a suitable function $f$). However, the "only if" direction is also required to obtain the result?

Comment: You are right, I corrected my answer.

Comment: Thanks, I understand now that the characterization of conditional independence. However, I no longer understand why this immediately yields an answer to the question. It seems to me that if the variable $X_L$ that we condition on is continuous, the definition of the paper does not apply (or it leads to an empty statement for Theorem 2).

Comment: Could you perhaps clarify whether you believe that what you write is still an answer to the question? How do you want to use the discrete result if $X_L$ is arbitrary?